# How do I search for literature containing specific math equations?

Tags: publications, mathematics, literature-search

When one looks for relevant literature, one turns to platforms such as Google Scholar or Web of Science. I want to search literature (or research articles) that include a specific mathematics equation. Is there a way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to search by the name of the equation (assuming it has one), as different papers may use different notations?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question with the equation by which you want to search so that we can see what you are looking for. If you don't want to give the exact equation here, then you can use an example that is identical in form (e.g. search on LaTeX, search on name of equation, etc.) though different in content.

Comment: I have come to know that https://www.zbmath.org/formulae/ has a feature something like this. Give it a go.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala So did you answer your own question?  Or do you want something different?  If so, please clarify.

Comment: There is something which is called "mathematics subject classification". When I was working at a university 20 years ago there were two journals (Zentralblatt für Mathematik and one other from the AMS) which published reviews of many articles and books, and also categorized them according the classification mentioned before. The already mentioned zbmath seems to be todays online version of the Zentralblatt, and I would assume the AMS paper is now also available online. Try googling this, maybe you can find the code for your topic.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are mentioning mathematics in the tags: Besides the databases and engines you mention there are two other important ressources:

- [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html)
- [zbMath](https://zbmath.org/)

Both are exclusively for mathematics and extremely reliable. The zbMath actually has [a search for formula](https://zbmath.org/formulae/) (as mentioned in the comments - thought I flesh it out as an answer)! Check out the "Example" button besides the search bar, to get to know how the engine works. I have to admit, that I haven't used this for my work up to now, but the example work nicely.